# How to navigate to a URL from a Power app

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have some customized list forms.

I would like to navigate to the site home page/other URL on success of the form.

Is there any possible method to accomplish this?

EDIT: Currently when the form is closed, the user is taken to the concerned list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Launch function.

For example

```
Launch("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

You can also pass parameters. Read the full documenation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param

Comment: Launch() opens the URL in a new tab. The previous tab remains open, and the user is taken to the list view.

Comment: I don't know that it's possible to leave the app without opening a new page.